# Firebase SignIn Using a Token from REST API

Tags: android, ios, firebase, rest

I have whole project using Firebase REST API but I want start using Firebase SDKs (iOS/Android) without stop using Authentication REST API.
I have access to this tokens:

- access_token
- id_token
- refresh_token

Can I use them to log into Firebase Authentication SDKs iOS or/and Android?
If yes, how?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

These are only applicable through the rest API as you will have to authenticate within the module to invoke the user auth process.

To break it down, the `access_token` and `id_token` as interchangeable, the `refresh token` allows the client to request new a `id_token` when it expires or invoked manually.
But to my knowledge, there is no way to manually inject a refresh token into the auth state and would require something like the admin-sdk to create a custom auth token for cross-platform authentication.

In that situation, I would recommend a cloud function and using the custom auth to validate the user to migrate from the rest API to the firebase modules.

All you need to do is create a Cloud Function that on invoke, gets the users current `Auth.uid` (would be done with your provided `id_token`) - With the users `uid`, you can create a [custom sign-in token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk)
that being said, you can also sign in with a 3rd party JWT, but this is not recommended.